# Check if $\int_1^\infty\frac{1-\cos 2x}{x}dx$ converge or not

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions

Here is my attempt:

$$
\int_1^\infty\frac{1-\cos 2x}{x}dx
 = \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_1^b\frac{1-\cos 2x}{x}dx
 = \lim_{b \to \infty} \left[
               \int_1^b\frac{1}{x}dx - \int_1^b\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx
                       \right]
$$

I know that the first integral does not converges, but I don't know nothing about the second one.

Any hints on how to calculate $\int_1^b\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx$ ? I have tried many things with no luck...

Thanks!

Comment: Do the "many things" include an integration by parts ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yes, of course. I ended with $\frac{1}{4}(2x \sin2x + \cos2x)$

Comment: I have also tried $t=2x$ and than $\int \frac{\cos 2x}{x}dx = \int \frac{\cos t}{t}dt$ which was confusing to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By an integration by parts,$$\int_1^b\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx = \left[ \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}\right]_1^b + \int_1^b \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x^2}dx = \frac{\sin(2b)}{2b}- \frac{\sin(2)}{2} + \int_1^b \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x^2}dx$$

Now
$$\lim_{b \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sin(2b)}{2b}- \frac{\sin(2)}{2} = - \frac{\sin(2)}{2}$$

and because
$$\left|\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x^2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2x^2}$$

which is integrable, then
$$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x^2}dx \quad \text{exists}$$

You deduce that $$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx \quad \text{exists}$$

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for! What did you choose for $u,u',v,v'$?

Comment: $u=\sin(2x)/2$ and $v=1/x$, the idea is to differentiate the $1/x$ part to make appear a $1/x^2$ which gives an absolutely convergent integral.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\frac{1-\cos2x}{x}dx&=2\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x}dx&&(\because1-\cos2x=2\sin^2x)\\
&\ge2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4}}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}dx&&\left(\because\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty\left[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4},\frac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}\right]\subset[1,\infty)\right)\\
&\ge2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac12\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4}}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}}\frac{dx}{x}&&\left(\because\sin^2x\ge\frac12\:\forall\:x\in\left[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4},\frac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}\right]\right)\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac\pi2\times\frac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}&&\left(\because\frac1x\ge\frac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}\:\forall\:x\in \left[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{4},\frac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}\right]\right)\\
&\ge\frac25\sum_{k=3}^\infty\frac1k&&(\because 5k\ge4k+3\:\forall\:k\ge3)\\
&=\infty &&(\because\text{Harmonic sum diverges})
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

> *([Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals))* If the integral of a function $f$ is uniformly bounded over all intervals, and $g$ is a monotonically decreasing non-negative function, then the integral of $fg$ is a convergent improper integral.

Since the integral of $f(x) = \cos(2x)$ is uniformly bounded and $g(x) = 1/x$ is monotonically decreasing non-negative function, the integral $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos(2x)}{x}dx$ is convergent.

Since $\text{convergent} + \text{divergent} = \text{divergent}$, your integral diverges.

Comment: $f(x) = 1$ is also uniformly bounded, but clearly $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx$ does not converge.

Comment: @TomChen Sorry, I omitted the phrase "integral of". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but I am sorry, I can't use this theorem (didn't learn it yet).